# Remove grandchildren with certain class when grandparent is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

All these `anchor` tags have child `paragraph`s that have child `span`s.

When the user clicks any `anchor`, I want to remove the existing `grandparent` class from that particular `anchor`.

And if any `anchor` dosen't have the `grandparent` class, I want to remove the grandchildren element with `grandchild` class.

(*There are some `anchor` that doesn't have any class or grandchild nested. I added an example element for that*)[**In case it matters**]

```js
const grandparents = document.querySelectorAll('a');

grandparents.forEach(elem => {
  elem.addEventListener('click',()=>{
   elem.classList.remove('grandparent');
  }
  if (!elem.classList.contains('grandparent')) {
    //remove element with the class of 'grandchild';
  }
})
```

```html
<a href="#" class="grandparent">
  <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus, dolorum? <span class="grandchild">&#8226;</span></p>
</a>
<a href="#" class="grandparent">
  <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus, dolorum? <span class="grandchild">&#8226;</span></p>
</a>
<a href="#" class="grandparent">
  <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus, dolorum? <span class="grandchild">&#8226;</span></p>
</a>
<a href="#">
  <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus, dolorum? </p>
</a>
```

Comment: If you want something to happen when the user clicks, you need to put the code in an event listener.

Comment: `!elem.classList.contains('grandparent')` will always be true, since you just removed the class on the previous line. What's the point of that condition?

Comment: There's only _"I want..."_ but not what you've tried so far to fulfill this "request" and what problem(s) you have with that approach.

Comment: You can use `elem.querySelector(".grandchild")` to get a reference to grandchild element of elem.  If it's null, it doesn't have one.

Comment: You can get the grandchildren with `elem.querySelectorAll(".grandchild")`

Comment: I forgot to add the eventListener line. Sorry! But the questions remains the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments on your answer suggested, you need an event listener.  In this event listener, you can use `elem.querySelectorAll()` to get all grandchildren with the class `grandchild`, then loop over the elements and remove them.

Also, you can replace the `const grandparents = document.querySelectorAll('a')` with `const grandparents = document.querySelectorAll('.grandparent')` to make sure this only happens on tags with the `grandparent` class.

```js
const grandparents = document.querySelectorAll('.grandparent');
grandparents.forEach(elem => {
  elem.addEventListener('click', () => {
    elem.classList.remove('grandparent');
    const gc = elem.querySelectorAll('* > .grandchild');
    for (let i = 0; i < gc.length; i++) {
      gc[i].remove();
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<a href="#" class="grandparent">
  <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus, dolorum? <span class="grandchild">&#8226;</span></p>
</a>
<a href="#" class="grandparent">
  <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus, dolorum? <span class="grandchild">&#8226;</span></p>
</a>
<a href="#" class="grandparent">
  <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus, dolorum? <span class="grandchild">&#8226;</span></p>
</a>
<a href="#">
  <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus, dolorum? </p>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```js
const grandparents = document.querySelectorAll('a');

grandparents.forEach(elem => {
  elem.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (elem.classList.contains('grandparent'))
    elem.classList.remove('grandparent');
  else
    elem.querySelector('.grandchild')?.remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="#" class="grandparent">
  <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus, dolorum? <span class="grandchild">&#8226;</span></p>
</a>
<a href="#" class="grandparent">
  <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus, dolorum? <span class="grandchild">&#8226;</span></p>
</a>
<a href="#" class="grandparent">
  <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus, dolorum? <span class="grandchild">&#8226;</span></p>
</a>
<a href="#">
  <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus, dolorum? </p>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost have a solution written in your question.

> if any anchor doesn't have the grandparent class, I want to remove the grandchildren element with grandchild class.

**else**

> when the user clicks any anchor, I want to remove the existing grandparent class from that particular anchor.

```js
if (!elem.classList.contains('grandparent')) {
    //remove element with the class of 'grandchild';
  } else {
    // remove element class grandparent
}
```

This snippet can be further simplified.